# PostgreSQL performance, using ILIKE with just two percentages versus not at all

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm using ILIKE to search for the title of a row based on user input. When the user has nothing inputted (empty string), all rows should return.

Is there a performance difference if you query a SELECT statement with `ILIKE '%%'` versus without it at all? In other words, is it okay to just query ILIKE empty or should I get rid of it in my query if there is no search filter text?

Comment: after doing some testing in oracle (don't have postgresql db right now) , even with `'%%'` it still do a filter scan which do cause some resource, so for the performance I think it will be better to use no filter text at all.

Comment: Okay, that's what I suspected. Thank you!

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there a performance difference if you query a SELECT statement with ILIKE '%%' versus without it at all?

The two queries:

```
select *
from some_table
where some_column ILIKE '%'
```

and

```
select *
from some_table
```

will return different results.

The first one is equivalent to `where some_column is not null` - so it will never return rows where `some_column` is null, but the second one will.

So it's not only about performance, but also about correctness.

Performance wise they will most likely be identical - doing a `Seq Scan` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

On PostgreSQL (13.1) the two queries are not equivalent:

```
test=# select count(*) from test_ilike where test_string ilike '%%';
 count  
--------
 100000
(1 row)

Time: 87,211 ms
```

```
test=# select count(*) from test_ilike where test_string ilike '';
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

Time: 85,521 ms
```

```
test=# explain analyze select count(*) from test_ilike where test_string ilike '%%';
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2333.97..2333.99 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=86.859..86.860 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on test_ilike  (cost=0.00..2084.00 rows=99990 width=0) (actual time=0.022..81.497 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Filter: (test_string ~~* '%%'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.313 ms
 Execution Time: 86.893 ms
(5 rows)
Time: 87,582 ms
```

```
test=# explain analyze select count(*) from test_ilike where test_string ilike '';
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2084.00..2084.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=83.223..83.224 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on test_ilike  (cost=0.00..2084.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=83.219..83.219 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: (test_string ~~* ''::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 100000
 Planning Time: 0.104 ms
 Execution Time: 83.257 ms
(6 rows)

Time: 83,728 ms
```

Comment: I think the question is `... ILIKE '%'` vs. not having an ILIKE condition at all.